# How can I save a Pages document as .docx?

Tags: pages, ms-office, word-processor

I've tried to save a pages document as a `*.docx` for Microsoft Office.

Pages is able to **open**, **edit** and **(auto-)save** existing `*.docx` documents.
However, there is no option to export or save a duplicate as `*.docx`?

- Is this a missing compability feature and are there plug-ins for pages to add that functionality?

Comment: I have the same problem, but the answers here seems to be slightly outdated. A reference of the version of the OS to which this question was related would be nice.

Comment: For example, with `Lion` TextEdit isn't able to save under `.docx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem to be a missing feature. As I see it, you have two options:

1. Export as `*.doc` using **File** -> **Export**. While not ideal, I imagine almost everything that supports `*.docx` also supports `*.doc`.
2. TextEdit is able to save as `*.docx`. Of course this is only really an option if your formatting is simple.

Comment: It's really strange that Apple would support .docx in TextEdit but not in Pages. This is especially strange because Office'08 already supported that format, while Pages came out one year later.

Comment: Actually, TextEdit will be fine for most cases as it supports **rich formatting**! :)

Comment: This answer needs some update.
For example, with `Lion` TextEdit isn't able to save under `.docx` format.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the file you want to export in **Pages**.
2. Select all; Copy
3. Create a new, empty file in **TextEdit** and save it with the name you want as a `.docx` file.
4. Open the file in **Pages**
5. Paste your content into the `.docx` file
6. Save the `.docx` file

(Or create an automator workflow to do all this, if you find yourself doing it often)

Comment: Is it possible to trigger such an automator workflow from within of pages? That would be awesome!

Comment: OK, let me try to work that out. I suspect the answer is yes.

Comment: Both TextEdit and Pages have less than ideal scripting dictionaries. Sadly, this will take some doing. I suspect it can be automated, but it won't happen tonight.

Comment: I will make sure to attach a bounty if you get it to work in order to honor your efforts :)

Comment: Just for reference, the scripting project is going badly.I'm not writing it off yet, but without a breakthrough, this isn't going to work. Also, I have Pages '08 on my machine, which can import docx but can't save them, so I can't test this without spending money to upgrade...

Comment: That's sad, but thank you for your undertaking!