# How to export Pages document to .docx?

Tags: macos, pages, formatting

This question is pretty similar to this one:

[How can I save a Pages document to .docx?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44098/22003)

Unfortunatly, the answers provided to this old one don't work with:

```
Mountain Lion        10.8.5
Pages ’09            4.3
```

I already found a transition path which is going through the following steps:

1. From `Pages` export as a `.doc`,
2. Open the `.doc` file with `LibreOffice` and save it as a `.docx` file.

Unfortunately, this conversion leads to files containing a lot of useless
list styles which are a real trouble to continue working on the converted file. See this related question on these useless styles:

[Get rid of WW8Num* list styles upon exporting from Pages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/143533/22003).

---

How to export a `Pages` document under `.docx` format?

Comment: With Pages '11 (v5.2.x) you'll have the .docx export option - but I think you need OS X 10.9.x Mavericks for this to work - but Mavericks can be installed/upgraded for free, so maybe a valid solution.

Comment: Does this conversion method permit to get rid of the bunch of 'WW8Num*` list styles?

Answer (score 1):

The current Pages beta on iCloud.com gave a very faithful export from Pages > Word .docx format (I shared the document with myself by email, but there may be a more appropriate way for you to do it). You can drag and drop a Pages file from your desktop into iCloud without fear of irreparably converting your original Pages '09 file.